# Drawing every VisualStylesElement?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have made an application that can render and save a given element.

```
 With windowElements

        .Add("statusBar", _
            VisualStyleElement.Window.CloseButton.Normal) 'need each element

    End With

    'calculate rect

    Dim heightMinusFrame As Integer = _
        ClientRectangle.Height - frameThickness



    ' Calculate the status bar rectangles and add them
    ' to the Dictionary of rectangles.





    For Each entry In windowElements

        SetRenderer(entry.Value)
        elementRectangles("statusBar") = _
       New Rectangle(0, 0, elemsize.Width, elemsize.Height)

        Dim image = New Bitmap(elemsize.Width, elemsize.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        Dim gfx = Graphics.FromImage(image)
        gfx.Clear(Color.Transparent)

        renderer.DrawBackground(gfx, _
            elementRectangles(entry.Key))

        image.Save("btn.png")
    Next entry
```

This works great except I have to specify which element I want, and I essentially want all of them. Is there some sort of for each that could iterate through all the possible elements?

Thanks

Comment: Please use [Using](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/disposeobj.htm) to dispose your many objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean [Parts and States](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773210%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)?